# Converting Integer to Byte Array not working in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

So I am working on a program where I am dealing with really large Integers. For this, I am wanting to use the [BigInteger Class in System.Numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=net-5.0). This seems to work sometimes, but when I run into large enough values (which is common), it breaks.

I use this idea twice in my program, here is my first attempt, which sometimes works:

```
        'encrypt
        For i As Integer = 0 To IntegerList.Count() - 1
            'create a Byte Array for the exponentiation
            Dim ByteList As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(IntegerList(i) ^ eInteger)

            'create a BigInteger using ByteList
            Dim ExpInt = New BigInteger(ByteList)

            'do mod operation
            Dim ModInteger As Integer = ExpInt Mod nInteger

            'add to list
            IntegerList(i) = ModInteger
        Next
```

However, like I said, I think this breaks when the numbers are large enough. For example here is 72^13:

[image]

This seems okay to me, but a little weird. However, when stuff gets big enough, like in 72^967, I get this:

[image]

Here is my second attempt in my code, however this never works since the numbers are much larger than the first attempt:

```
        'decrypt string
        Dim ByteList As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(EncryptedInteger ^ dInteger)
        Dim EncryptedBigInteger = New BigInteger(ByteList)

        Dim ExpInteger = New BigInteger(ByteList)

        Dim ModInteger As Integer = EncryptedBigInteger Mod nInteger

        DecryptIntListBox.Items.Add(ModInteger)
```

Here are two alternatives that I tried, but the ^ operator does not work with BigInteger:

This would have been convenient

```
        'decrypt string
        Dim EncryptByteList As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(EncryptedInteger)
        Dim dByteList As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(dInteger)

        Dim EncryptedBigInteger = New BigInteger(EncryptByteList)
        Dim dBigInteger = New BigInteger(dByteList)

        EncryptedBigInteger = EncryptedBigInteger ^ dBigInteger

        Dim ModInteger As Integer = EncryptedBigInteger Mod nInteger

        DecryptIntListBox.Items.Add(ModInteger)
```

This seems like something. Could I loop `EncryptedBigInteger = EncryptedBigInterger * EncryptedInteger` dInteger times? The operation will work, I just don't know if I will break something

```
        'decrypt string
        Dim EncryptByteList As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(EncryptedInteger)

        Dim EncryptedBigInteger = New BigInteger(EncryptByteList)

        EncryptedBigInteger = EncryptedBigInteger ^ dInteger

        Dim ModInteger As Integer = EncryptedBigInteger Mod nInteger

        DecryptIntListBox.Items.Add(ModInteger)
```

So, how can I make this work? I **know** that BigInteger can hold the numbers that I need, but I just can't seem to get them into the class. From my research, using a Byte Array is the most logical way to do this.

For context, I am writing code that gives an example of RSA Encryption/Decryption and shows the process.

**Edit:**

I tried the `EncryptedBigInteger = EncryptedBigInterger * EncryptedInteger` method and got this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'
```

Comment: Please post the actual code as text not images, this is covered in the [FAQ] and [tour].

Comment: @JeremyThompson fixed

Comment: Your two examples, 72^13 and 72^967, aren't integers. 72^13 can be represented by a double, 72^967 can't.

Comment: Whether `EncyptedBigInteger ^ dInteger` would work depends entirely on how the VB compiler handles the VB exponentiation operator.  Ideally, it would recognize that there is a shared `Pow` that operates on `BigInteger` and compile down to a call to that function (similarly to how I would expect the operator to work on the built-in types), but I'm not sure if that's actually the case.  Unlike VB, less-civilized .NET languages (most notably C#) do not include exponentiation as a built-in operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, I have achieved what I needed by doing this:

```
        'create byte array
        Dim EncryptedByteList As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(EncryptedInteger)

        'create BigInts
        Dim EncryptedBigInteger = New BigInteger(EncryptedByteList)
        Dim StaticEncryptedBigInteger = New BigInteger(EncryptedByteList)

        'calculate EncryptedInteger ^ dInteger
        For i As Integer = 1 To dInteger - 1
            EncryptedBigInteger *= StaticEncryptedBigInteger
        Next

        'do mod operation
        Dim ModInteger As Integer = EncryptedBigInteger Mod nInteger

        'output
        DecryptIntListBox.Items.Add(ModInteger)
```

Still open to suggestions if there is a better way.